# Authenticate ORDS webservice with Basic Auth

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I created a new user in Apex through the front end(not script) and assigned "Restful Services" role to it. In my privilege, I added my protected module and added the same role "Restful Services" also via front end.
However, as soon as I do this, I can no longer access my web service through Postman as I get 401 error. I was able to do this without authentication. Needless to say, I added Basic Auth in Postman with the new user and password.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Needless to say, I added Basic Auth in Postman with the new user and password." Ok, and? did that not work?

Comment: Thats when I got the 401 error. As soon as  I link my privilege with rolle "restful Services" to my module, I cannot access it even though I give the basic auth in postman with username and password.

Comment: Basic Auth is slow and not recommended, but if you go that way, it only works for database users, and not apex users. You'll have to add the privilege for your rest API to the 'SQL Developer' ords role to use basic Auth with your schema account

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith, I will try to do this. My recommendation was Oauth2 but the client wants it this way between internal applications.

Comment: oauth2 is perfect for internal applications